# How can I store the IP and Port that are separated by ":" to two variables?

Tags: bash

I want to extract the IP and Port from a variable. I have tried to use this:

```
ADDR=1.2.3.4:12345
IP=${ADDR##:}
PORT=${ADDR%:}
```

However, this assigns the entire address to both variables.

How can I store the the IP and Port to two variables?

Comment: try `IP=${ADDR##*:}`

Comment: Thanks @Marco , that works.  Do you know why it works without * on other machine, and they are both very similar 20.04 Ubuntu

Comment: @DenisZ What is different in the other machine you mention? Does it have a different OS? A different OS version? Are you using a different shell?

Comment: Thanks @BeastOfCaerbannog All the same Ubutnu 20.04, but I went through script again, but was working by accident, when I tried it manually also didn't match, so my bad.

Comment: Note that this assumes IPv4, since IPv6 will have colons in the IP address itself

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You got it wrong, has to be like this:

```
ADDR=1.2.3.4:12345
IP=${ADDR%:*}
PORT=${ADDR##*:}
```

Since there is only one matching occurrence of `:` for IPv4, in this case it doesn't matter if you match first or last occurrence. However, in case of IPv6, it's best to match last occurrence for port. In addition, it seems you accidentally switched IP and PORT.

Also see here: [Bash cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/bash) and [Bash Hacker wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal)

In short, substring removal works like this:

- `${variable#pattern}`: Remove from the beginning of string, first match
- `${variable##pattern}`: Remove from the beginning of string, last match
- `${variable%pattern}`: Remove from the end of string, first match
- `${variable%%pattern}`: Remove from the end of string, last match

It can be necessary to include wildcard (`*`) in the pattern if you want to match only part of a word, that is not separated by whitespace.

Comment: Thanks @Artur.  This works.  If no port listed than PORT is then also IP, Should I use different method to get PORT null if no ':'

Comment: Yes, that would be a condition you should handle accordingly.

Comment: but how to get PORT variable in no ':' in variable?, btw please update your `${VARIABLE%%PATTERN}`  for end of string match

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have a new question. Thank you.

Comment: +1 A suitable expansion as well for this task is the replacement i.e. `${Var//pattern/replacement}` ... e.g. `${ADDR//*:/}` and `${ADDR//:*/}` ... It might be handy if you want to keep the `:` with the port e.g. `${ADDR//*:/:}`

Comment: It's not guaranteed that there will be only one `:`, as IPv6 addresses will always have more than one (e.g. `[2001:db8::1234]:80`), so first vs last does matter. Your solution is the only one that works for this case, although it needs `${ADDR##:*}`.

Comment: @user1686 My answer was written under the assumption that it is for IPv4. I agree that IPv6 is a different scenario, but since this isn't mentioned at all, I assumed it wasn't relevant here. But good point.

Answer (score 7):

Since your string has no spaces and no shell globs i.e.:

```bash
addr="1.2.3.4:12345"
```

(*It's a good practice to quote your string BTW*)

You can simply populate an array with the IP and the PORT like so:

```bash
a=(${addr//\:/ })
```

That will replace each `:` in the string with a space   inside the `()` and voila! it's an array now ... That would work for things like MAC addresses as well, but expect more array elements.

**Notice**: This will work for **IPv4** … For **IPv6**, you can do something like this instead:

```bash
addr="[1fff:0:a88:85a3::ac1f]:8001"
addr="${addr/\[/}"
a=(${addr/\]\:/ })
```

**Alternatively**: You can automate this to handle both **IPv4** and **IPv6** with e.g. a condition like this:

```bash
if [[ "$addr" =~ [\:]{2,} ]]
  then
  # It's IPv6 ... Do this
  addr="${addr/\[/}"
  a=(${addr/\]\:/ })
  else
  # It's IPv4 ... Do this instead
  a=(${addr//\:/ })
  fi
```

And then, you can call and print the array elements like so:

```bash
echo -e "IP: ${a[0]}\nPORT: ${a[1]}"
```

Then simply use it like so:

```bash
$ addr="1.2.3.4:12345"
$ a=(${addr//:/ })
$ echo -e "IP: ${a[0]}\nPORT: ${a[1]}"
IP: 1.2.3.4
PORT: 12345
```

Or to handle empty or no PORT like so:

```bash
$ addr="1.2.3.4:" # or even addr="1.2.3.4"
$ a=(${addr//:/ })
$ echo -e "IP: ${a[0]}\nPORT: ${a[1]:-EMPTY}"
IP: 1.2.3.4
PORT: EMPTY
```

As far as manipulation and evaluation goes ... Please see the demonstration below:

```bash
$ addr="1.2.3.4:12345"
$ # Populating an array "a" with the elements around the ":" from the string in "$addr"
a=(${addr//:/ })
$ # Assigning array "a" elements to parameters
ip="${a[0]}"
port="${a[1]}"
$ # Assigning array "a" length(number of elements) to a parameter
len="${#a[@]}"
$ # Printing array length
echo "${#a[@]}"
echo "$len"
2
2
$ # Printing all array "a" elements
echo "${a[@]}"
1.2.3.4 12345
$ # Printing array "a" elements by index
echo "IP: ${a[0]} and PORT: ${a[1]}"
IP: 1.2.3.4 and PORT: 12345
$ # Printing array elements from parameters
echo "IP: $ip and PORT: $port"
IP: 1.2.3.4 and PORT: 12345
$ # Evaluating by array length
[ "${#a[@]}" == "2" ] && echo "IP: $ip and PORT: $port" || echo "IP: $ip and PORT: NA"
[ "$len" == "2" ] && echo "IP: $ip and PORT: $port" || echo "IP: $ip and PORT: NA"
IP: 1.2.3.4 and PORT: 12345
IP: 1.2.3.4 and PORT: 12345
$ # Evaluating by array element/parameter string length "-z"(zero)
[ -z "${a[1]}" ] && echo "IP: ${a[0]} and PORT: NA" || echo "IP: ${a[0]} and PORT: ${a[1]}"
[ -z "$port" ] && echo "IP: $ip and PORT: NA" || echo "IP: $ip and PORT: $port"
IP: 1.2.3.4 and PORT: 12345
IP: 1.2.3.4 and PORT: 12345
$ 
$ 
$ # This is a demonstration when there is only IP4 and no port 
$ addr="1.2.3.4"
$ a=(${addr//:/ })
$ ip="${a[0]}"
port="${a[1]}"
$ len="${#a[@]}"
$ echo "${#a[@]}"
echo "$len"
1
1
$ echo "${a[@]}"
1.2.3.4
$ echo "IP: ${a[0]} and PORT: ${a[1]}"
IP: 1.2.3.4 and PORT: 
$ echo "IP: $ip and PORT: $port"
IP: 1.2.3.4 and PORT: 
$ [ "${#a[@]}" == "2" ] && echo "IP: $ip and PORT: $port" || echo "IP: $ip and PORT: NA"
[ "$len" == "2" ] && echo "IP: $ip and PORT: $port" || echo "IP: $ip and PORT: NA"
IP: 1.2.3.4 and PORT: NA
IP: 1.2.3.4 and PORT: NA
$ [ -z "${a[1]}" ] && echo "IP: ${a[0]} and PORT: NA" || echo "IP: ${a[0]} and PORT: ${a[1]}"
[ -z "$port" ] && echo "IP: $ip and PORT: NA" || echo "IP: $ip and PORT: $port"
IP: 1.2.3.4 and PORT: NA
IP: 1.2.3.4 and PORT: NA
```

**Notice**: While this `arr=(${parameter//delimiter/ })` hack is a simple and nice thing to know that works perfectly as described above, but you should know it's also prone to shell word splitting if your string contains spaces and also prone to shell globbing if your string contains globbing characters e.g `*` ... So it wouldn't be advised then.

Comment: Thanks @Raffa I like this solution the best, as it seems the shortest.  Yet I need to use $ip and $Port as variables for later in script, and if port is not present it should be empty so I can test with `if [ -z $port ]; then....fi`.  Technically I could use 'if [ -z "${a[1]}" ]; ...' I presume.

Comment: @DenisZ Sure ... I updated the answer for that.

Comment: Wonderful @Raffa, you give a full guide

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative approach using bash's built-in `read` command:

```
IFS=: read IP PORT <<<"$ADDR"
```

Ex. (you should avoid ALL-CAPS names for your own shell variables - they are informally reserved):

```
$ addr=1.2.3.4:12345
$ IFS=: read ip port <<<"$addr"
$ printf 'IP is %s and PORT is %s\n' "$ip" "${port:-EMPTY}"
IP is 1.2.3.4 and PORT is 12345
```

This method will also handle the case where the :PORT is missing:

```
$ addr=1.2.3.4
$ IFS=: read ip port <<<"$addr"
$ printf 'IP is %s and PORT is %s\n' "$ip" "${port:-EMPTY}"
IP is 1.2.3.4 and PORT is EMPTY
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the number of sub-strings or if there many, you can use arrays also.

For example to split a MAC address like `b0:25:a1:2d:b1:22` into its parts, you can use:

```
IFS=':' read -r -a mac <<< "b0:25:a1:2d:b1:22"
```

The sub-strings will be stored in the array elements `"${mac[0]}"` through `"${mac[5]}"`.