# How to extract part of var with substring substition if exists

Tags: bash

I need to extract IP and PORT (if exists) from address. I currently use following and it works if address has :port, but if it doesn't PORT variable becomes also IP.  How to have PORT to be null if no port specified

```
#ADDR=1.2.3.4:12345
ADDR=1.2.3.4
IP=${ADDR%:*}
PORT=${ADDR#*:}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So answer was already given in the previous question by steeldriver

https://askubuntu.com/a/1458499/1177212